# Toggle Radio Button for showing detail

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to toggle my pageblocksection on radiobutton but it is not working.
I am sharing my code with you.

vf page

```
apex:page StandardController="DetailLog__c" extensions="detailctrl" sidebar="false">    
    <apex:form >
        <apex:selectRadio value="{!radiobtn}">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!PageDetail}"/>
            <apex:actionSupport event="onChange" reRender="cpBlock"/>
        </apex:selectRadio>  
        <apex:pageBlock id="cpBlock" >
            <apex:pageblockSection title="Personal Detail" rendered="{!show}">
                <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.First_Name__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.Middle_Name__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.Last_Name__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.Date_of_Birth__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.Father_Name__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.Mother_Name__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.Permanent_Address__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.PAN_No__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.Mobile_Number__c}"/>                
            </apex:pageblockSection>                                                               
             <apex:pageblockSection title="Professional Detail" rendered="{!hide}">                
                <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.First_Name__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.Last_Name__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.Email_ID__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.Fax_Number__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.Office_Address__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.Passport_Number__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.Desgination__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.Age__c}"/>
            </apex:pageblockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>    
    </apex:form>
/apex:page>
```

Controller Extension

```
public class detailctrl {
    public String radiobtn{get;set;}

    public Boolean show
    {   
        get{ return radiobtn == 'Option1';}
    }

    public Boolean hide
    {            
        get{ return radiobtn == 'Option2';}                                                            
    } 

    public List<SelectOption> getPageDetail()
    {        
        List<SelectOption> options=new List<SelectOption>();            
        options.add(new SelectOption('Option1','Personal Detail'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Option2','Professional Detail'));
        return options;
    }

    public detailctrl(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {        
        radiobtn='Option2';      
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find two root cause for your solution not to be working.

1. You are using `onChange` instead of `onchange`. Since Javascript is case sensitive it won't trigger the appropriate event.
2. You are trying to use `onchange` along with radio button. Its better to use `onclick` over `onchange`. You can find the reason for this [here](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/forms/radio/onclick-onchange.php).

Hope this helps.